# Using jQuery to hide drop-down, but it fails

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are two drop-downs i'm using in my document. One is visible, one i have to hide. Below is the script I have used to hide the drop-down:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('span[ds="Product Plan Type"]').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    });
</script>
```

Using the above code: initially the drop-down disappears, but if another drop-down is used to select any other option, when processed for that, the page refreshes and shows the drop-down back.
Could anyone suggest something?

Comment: is your ds attribute?

Comment: try hiding it from css...

Comment: I have no idea about it. I saw similar code somewhere and used it for my document. Could you refer any article from which i can take help?

Comment: @user2902792 add ur render html..

Comment: @Jai I didn't get what you said. Could you elaborate?

Comment: What i meant is give it a class name and add the display attribute to none.

Answer (score 0):

if your second drop down is not required during first load then you can set them hidden in code itlsef like

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" style="visibility:hidden">
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

now as per your statement second drop down get filled base on first value selected (during page load)
so you can place javascript code where you can check if value =Product Plan Type
then  you can how second drop down by javascript or you can do that using server side as well

Answer (score 0):

use css display on element which you have hide

```
 style="display:none"
```